# Stuck on a level in Think Different

Tags: think-different

[image]

How do I solve this and what's the answer?

Comment: What does the hint say?

Comment: I'm going to guess 9.

Comment: Have you tried thinking differently.

Comment: What level number is this?

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are one big number per row and the solution is a simple addition:

```
  5749827
+ 3864759
= 9614586
```

So the answer is 6.